# How to create a Row from a given case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine that you have the following case classes:

```
case class B(key: String, value: Int)
case class A(name: String, data: B)
```

Given an instance of `A`, how do I create a Spark `Row`? e.g.

```
val a = A("a", B("b", 0))
val row = ???
```

NOTE: Given `row` I need to be able to get data with:

```
val name: String = row.getAs[String]("name")
val b: Row = row.getAs[Row]("data")
```

Comment: thought about accepting an answer?

Answer (score 8):

The following seems to match what you're looking for.

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0

scala> val a = A("a", B("b", 0))
a: A = A(a,B(b,0))

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[A].schema
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: integer (nullable = false)

val values = a.productIterator.toSeq.toArray

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
val row: Row = new GenericRowWithSchema(values, schema)

scala> val name: String = row.getAs[String]("name")
name: String = a

// the following won't work since B =!= Row
scala> val b: Row = row.getAs[Row]("data")
java.lang.ClassCastException: B cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
  ... 55 elided
```

Comment: Considering that it doesn't correctly encode even simple data (not to mention complex types) I think it does more harm than good, unless you at least stress out, that output is not necessarily a valid `Row` object (by valid I mean one, that can be used with `RowEncoder`).

Comment: What do you mean by _"Considering that it doesn't correctly encode even simple data (not to mention complex types)"_? And what about _"that output is not necessarily a valid Row object " since the OP asked about a `Row` object which `GenericRowWithSchema` inherits from? Can you show an example that would prove your point? I'd appreciate.

Comment: Of course. Let's assume that `Dataset.map` or similar method returns object of the same shape as `row` in your example. There is no `Encoder` that can correctly encode this data (Kryo and Java aside). MCVE: `spark.createDataset(Seq(row))(RowEncoder(Encoders.product[A].schema))`. This of course propagates to any collection type with product.

Comment: Works well for me!

Answer (score 1):

Very short but probably not the fastest as it first creates a dataframe and then collects it again :

```
import session.implicits._
val row = Seq(a).toDF().first()
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jacek Laskowski answer is great!

To complete:

- Here some syntactic sugar:

```scala
val row = Row(a.productIterator.toSeq: _*)
```

- And a recursive method if you happen to have nested case classes

```scala
def productToRow(product: Product): Row = {
  val sequence = product.productIterator.toSeq.map {
    case product : Product => productToRow(product)
    case e => e
  }
  Row(sequence : _*)
}
```

Comment: could you provide some docs on this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there exist a public API that can do it directly. Internally Spark uses `Encoder.toRow` method to convert objects `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow`, but this method is private. You could try to:

- Obtain `Encoder` for the class:

  ```
  val enc: Encoder[A] = ExpressionEncoder()
  ```
- Use reflection to access `toRow` method and set it to accessible.
- Call it to convert object to `UnsafeRow`.
- Obtain `RowEncoder` for the expected schema (`enc.schema`).
- Convert `UnsafeRow` to `Row`.

I haven't tried this, so I cannot guarantee it will work or not.